# How can I toggle CSS class on component by clicking on another component?

Tags: angular

I have two components : 
- main component : app.component
- menu component : menu/menu.component

I want to toggle a CSS class of main component element by clicking on menu component element ?

How can I bind it ?

My structure

```
 -app
    app.component.html
    app.component.ts
    -menu
          menu.component.html
          menu.component.ts
```

Answer (score 1):

Use standard Angular mechanisms for communicating from child component to parent (`@Output()` properties), together with `@HostBinding` which binds properties to classes etc. on the component element.

**main**

Template:

```
<menu-component (clicked)="click()"></menu-component>
<div>I am styled</div>
```

TS:

```
@HostBinding('class.foo') public foo = false; 
click() { this.foo = true; }
```

CSS:

```
:host(.foo) div { color: red }
```

**menu**

Template:

```
<div (click)="click()">Click me</div>
```

TS:

```
@Output() clicked;
click() { this.clicked.emit(); }
```